# How to properly call models in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, models

I'm getting this `Notice` when loading a model.

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

        Severity: Notice

        Message: Undefined property: Users::$select

        Filename: controllers/users.php

        Line Number: 11
```

This is my Controller (users.php)

```
 <?php  
 class Users extends CI_Controller{  

 public function index(){  
     //load the database  
     $this->load->database();  
     //load the model  
     $this->load->model('users_model');  
     //load the method of model  
     $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
     //return the data in view  
     $this->load->view('users_view', $data);  
  }  
 }  
 ?>
```

This is my Model (users_model.php)

```
<?php  
 class Users_model extends CI_Model  
 {  
  function __construct()  
  {  
     // Call the Model constructor  
     parent::__construct();  
  }  
  //we will use the select function  
  public function select()  
  {  
     //data is retrive from this query  
     $query = $this->db->get('users');  
     return $query;  
  }  
 }  
 ?>
```

This is my View (users_view.php)

```
<table border="1">  
  <tbody>  
     <tr>  
        <td>Id</td>  
        <td>First Name</td>  
        <td>Last Name</td>  
        <td>E-mail ID</td>  
        <td>Password</td>  
        <td>Gender</td>  
        <td>Phone</td>  
        <td>Address</td>  
        <td>Is Admin</td>  
     </tr>  
     <?php  
     foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
     {  
        ?><tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->fname;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->lname;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->password;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->gender;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->phone;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->admin;?></td>  
        </tr>  
     <?php }  
     ?>  
  </tbody>
```

I'm new to CodeIgniter, need some help to know where I'm going wrong with my code.

Comment: Change `$data['h']=$this->select->select();` to `$data['h']=$this->users_model->select();`

Comment: @Blinkydamo It worked. Thank You a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to the method of the model is wrong. 
You should call your `model` with the method you want to use in your `controller`, like this:

```
$this->load->model('users_model');  
$data['h']=$this->users_model->select();
```

**Edit**: when you load a model, you can send a second parameter as a rename of the model. Example:

```
$this->load->model('users_model', 'select');  
$data['h']=$this->select->select();
```

You should check the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html) for more information about loading models

Answer (score 3):

Don't load database in your controller, rather do that in your models. In manner of MVC arhitecture models are data layer, so queries and database work should be limited to models.

Views are presentation layer of your application and mostly are "what user see".

Controllers are logical part of aplication, which correlate bettween your views and models. So all logical work like loading views, models, data validation, data  processing from database to presentation layer and vice-versa should stay in controller.

When it comes to proper loading models answer above is excellent, but there is also few tricks you could be interested in.

```
<?php  
    Class Users extends CI_Controller {
     public function __CONSTRUCT () {
        parent::__CONSTRUCT();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
     }  

     public function index(){  
         //load the method of model  
         $data['h']=$this->user_model->select();  
         //return the data in view  
         $this->load->view('users_view', $data);  
      }  
     }  
     ?>
```

You can use magic methods like

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
        parent::__CONSTRUCT();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
     }
```

and load model inside. This allows to you to use model over whole class instead of loading model in each function.

Also if you want to multiple models you can do it in array.

```
  public function __CONSTRUCT() {
            parent::__CONSTRUCT();
            $this->load->model( array('user_model', 'model_2', 'model_3'));
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your controller to

```
<?php  
 class Users extends CI_Controller{
 public function index() {  
       //load the database  
       $this->load->database();  

       //load the model  
       $this->load->model('users_model');

       //load the method of model  
       $data['h']=$this->users_model->select_data();  


       //return the data in view  
       $this->load->view('users_view', $data);  
   }  
 }  
?>
```

Your model

```
<?php  
 class Users_model extends CI_Model  
 {  
  function __construct()  
   {  
    // Call the Model constructor  
     parent::__construct();  
   }  
//we will use the select function  
 public function select_data()  
 {  
 //data is retrive from this query  
 $query = $this->db->get('users');  
 return $query;  
   }  
   }  
?>
```

Your View

```
<table border="1">  
 <tbody>  
 <tr>  
    <td>Id</td>  
    <td>First Name</td>  
    <td>Last Name</td>  
    <td>E-mail ID</td>  
    <td>Password</td>  
    <td>Gender</td>  
    <td>Phone</td>  
    <td>Address</td>  
    <td>Is Admin</td>  
 </tr>  
 <?php  
 foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
 {  
    ?><tr>  
    <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->fname;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->lname;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->password;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->gender;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->phone;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->address;?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $row->admin;?></td>  
    </tr>  
 <?php } ?>  
 </tbody>
```

Comment: You should explain something and not just paste the code.